# About closed subspaces in infinite Dimensional HIlbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

How can I prove the following?

> Let $H$ be an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space. Show there exist closed vector subspaces $\{X_t:t\in[0,1]\}$ in $H$ so that $X_s\subset X_t$ for every $0\leq s < t \leq 1$.

*My attempt*

Given that $H$ is isomorphic to $L^2[0,1]$, I move to the function space.
Clearly considering $X_s = \{f\in L^2: f(x) = 0 \ \forall x > s\} $ then the condition is clearly satisfied. So two doubts here:

1. The question doesn't mention separability, but it's necessary for my argument (isomorphism). Is it necessary to prove the statement?
2. Can it be proven without resorting to working in another isomorphic space?

Comment: If your given Hilbert space is not separable, you can look at a separable infinite-dimensional closed subspace (pick an orthonormal basis and consider the closed linear span of a countably infinite subset).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think something like this may work :

Let $\{ a_i \}_{i\in\mathbb N}$ be orthogonal vectors, let $f:\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]\to \mathbb N$ be a bijective function and let, for any $s\in [0,1]$, $X_s = \overline{\mathrm{span}}\{ a_{f(t)} : t\in\mathbb Q\cap[0,s] \}$. Then $X_s$ is closed and if $0\leq s<t\leq 1$, we have $X_s\subset X_t$ indeed there is some $p\in\mathbb Q\cap ]s,t[$ and therefore $X_t$ contains $a_{f(p)}$ but $X_s$ doens't, indeed $a_{f(p)}$ is orthogonal to $X_s$. The inclusion $X_s\subseteq X_t$ is clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a clear proof! Really appreciate it.